# CucumberJS - Error: Step timed out after 5000 milliseconds at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Tags: javascript, timer, cucumberjs

I'm new to cucumberjs and just trying out my first attempt at running a feature. I've built the feature that is on the [cucumber-js github page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js). I get this error when trying to run it:

> Benjamins-MBP:Features Ben$ cucumber.js example.feature Feature:
>   Example feature
>
> As a user of cucumber.js   I want to have documentation on cucumber 
>   So that I can concentrate on building awesome applications
>
> Scenario: Reading documentation                   #
>   example.feature:6
>       Given I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository # StepDefinitions/myStepDefinition.js:4
>         Error: Step timed out after 5000 milliseconds
>             at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
>       When I go to the README file                    # StepDefinitions/myStepDefinition.js:15
>       Then I should see "Usage" as the page title     # StepDefinitions/myStepDefinition.js:22
>
> Failing scenarios: example.feature:6 # Scenario: Reading documentation
>
> 1 scenario (1 failed) 3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped) 0m05.001s

What would one do to try to make this feature pass, given it is the example feature on the cucumber-js github page so probably not incorrect?

Here is all the code:

```
    // features/step_definitions/myStepDefinitions.js

module.exports = function () {
  this.Given(/^I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository$/, function (callback) {
    // Express the regexp above with the code you wish you had.
    // `this` is set to a World instance.
    // i.e. you may use this.browser to execute the step:

    this.visit('https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js', callback);

    // The callback is passed to visit() so that when the job's finished, the next step can
    // be executed by Cucumber.
  });

  this.When(/^I go to the README file$/, function (callback) {
    // Express the regexp above with the code you wish you had. Call callback() at the end
    // of the step, or callback.pending() if the step is not yet implemented:

    callback.pending();
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see "(.*)" as the page title$/, function (title, callback) {
    // matching groups are passed as parameters to the step definition

    var pageTitle = this.browser.text('title');
    if (title === pageTitle) {
      callback();
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Expected to be on page with title " + title));
    }
  });
};
```

The feature:

```
Feature: Example feature
  As a user of cucumber.js
  I want to have documentation on cucumber
  So that I can concentrate on building awesome applications

  Scenario: Reading documentation
    Given I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository
    When I go to the README file
    Then I should see "Usage" as the page title
```

the world.js file:

```
// features/support/world.js
var zombie = require('zombie');
function World() {
  this.browser = new zombie(); // this.browser will be available in step definitions

  this.visit = function (url, callback) {
    this.browser.visit(url, callback);
  };
}

module.exports = function() {
  this.World = World;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this to remove the 5000 milliseconds :

**protractor.conf.js**

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
        'tests/e2e/support/env.js',
        'main.step.js',
        ...
    ],
    format: 'pretty', // or summary
    keepAlive: false
},
```

**env.js**

```
var configure = function () {
    this.setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
};

module.exports = configure;
```

> example :

**test.feature**

```
Feature: test
    I want test wait

    Scenario: Test call wait
        Given I wait "6" seconds
```

**main.step.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    this.World = require(__base +'tests/e2e/support/world.js').World;

    // I wait "{time}" seconds
    this.Given(/^I wait "?([^"]*)"? seconds$/, function (time) {
        return browser.sleep(time * 1000);
    });

};
```

**world.js**

```
var World, chai, chaiAsPromised;

chai             = require('chai');
chai_as_promised = require('chai-as-promised');

World = function World (callback) {
    chai.use(chai_as_promised);

    this.expect = chai.expect;

    callback();
};

module.exports.World = World;
```

Comment: where do you call the configure you've exported in `env.js?`

Comment: nevermind, it was not working due to an incorrect reference to the env file on my side. The configure gets called automagically()

Answer (score 5):

In my case I've had to set the default timeout in the defineSupportCode, because trying to modify the timeout in the webdriver didn't provide any effect

```
defineSupportCode(function({Given, When, Then, setDefaultTimeout}) {

    setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

    Given('I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository', function() {
```

[Refer to this part of the doc](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md)

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the `this.Given` in the step definitions with the syntax used for a `promise`, is what has fixed it for me on two different OSX environments.

Here is the promise syntax that works:

```
this.Given(/^I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository$/, function () {
  // Notice how `callback` is omitted from the parameters
  return this.visit('https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js');

  // A promise, returned by zombie.js's `visit` method is returned to Cucumber.
});
```

Comment: Just removing the callback from the parameters proved sufficient for me.