# Protractor ununderstandable fails - function timed out ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds

Tags: async-await, protractor

I really need your help. I'm writing Protractor tests in Typescript 3.0.3 with async/await notation.
My problem is that after clicking SAVE button a p-dialog shows up with button OK.
Besides the button there is also a message like: 'Success'.
So in my test I want to check this message and click OK button.

1) When I do this:

```
await $("p-dialog[header='Success'] button[label='Ok']").click();
```

then it clicks OK button but also fails with

```
function timed out ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds
```

2) When at the beginging I try to getText of check if it's displayed

```
console.log("is enabled " + await $("p-dialog[header='Success'] > div > div > span").isEnabled());
```

or

```
console.log( await $("p-dialog[header='Success'] > div > div > span").getText());
```

then it also fails and doesn't display anything from above two:

```
function timed out ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds
```

All locators are correct  - I checked them.
Also the funny thing is that I have another

> p-dialog

under the same locator but in a different moment of my process and it works like a charm...
The difference between those it is a message nothing else.

Can you please help me with that. 
Why is this failing?
How to increase timeout from 5000 to i.e. 15000?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Jasmine or Cucumber with Protractor?

Comment: I'm using Protractor

Comment: Protractor is a basically just a wrapper for selenium webdriver and generally requires a testing framework to execute tests in meaningful way. It comes with Jasmine by default but that error seems to be associated with a lot of cucumber questions. Do your tests look like [this](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction) (jasmine) or [this](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/)(cucumber)

Comment: It's in Gherkin/Cucumber...

Comment: Cool there seem to be a number of related answers in that case. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862078/protractor-and-cucumber-function-timed-out-using-async-await) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852631/function-timed-out-after-5000-milliseconds-angular-4-protractor-cucumber?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409724/cucumberjs-error-step-timed-out-after-5000-milliseconds-at-timer-listontimeou/34651921).

Comment: I've tried with this timeouts from your examples but in my Cucumber 5.0.0 and CucumberFlow 3.2.0 it's impossible to set it this way.
But the good news is that I created a new step with a new method and moved a troublesome part there and now works :) - however it's freaking silly.
Thank you anyway for your time :)